# Problema al ejecutar consulta simple en Hibernate: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy empezando con Hibernate comparando con tutoriales y haciendo una consulta super simple me da el siguiente error:

```
may. 18, 2022 9:24:25 P. M. org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.0.0.Final
may. 18, 2022 9:24:25 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
may. 18, 2022 9:24:25 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
may. 18, 2022 9:24:25 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/videogames?serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid]
may. 18, 2022 9:24:25 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=vpm}
may. 18, 2022 9:24:25 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
may. 18, 2022 9:24:25 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
may. 18, 2022 9:24:26 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
may. 18, 2022 9:24:26 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Juego'
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:754)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:120)
    at hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Juego'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1626)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitEntityWithJoins(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1546)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitFromClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:627)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1219)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:621)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1132)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:394)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:741)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:738)
    ... 2 more
```

Mi código se compone unicamente de 1 entidad y el main que hace todo

Mi main es tan simple como lo siguiente:

```
package hibernate;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/videogames?serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid");
        settings.put(Environment.USER, "vpm");
        settings.put(Environment.PASS, "vpm");
        settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

        settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

        configuration.setProperties(settings);

        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Juego.class);

        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory  sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        
        List<Juego> listaJuegos = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("from Juego", Juego.class).getResultList(); // <-- Aqui da el error
        
        System.out.println(listaJuegos.size());
    }
}
```

Basicamente es traerse todas los registros de la tabla, pero por alguna razón me da el error que he mostrado. La línea exacta donde da error es

```
List<Juego> listaJuegos = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("from Juego", Juego.class).getResultList();
```

La clase Juego donde esta la entidad es:

```
package hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "whislist")
public class Juego implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4151736911313824434L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="idWhislist")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long idJuego;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int posicion;

    public long getIdJuego() {
        return idJuego;
    }

    public void setIdJuego(long idJuego) {
        this.idJuego = idJuego;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getPosicion() {
        return posicion;
    }

    public void setPosicion(int posicion) {
        this.posicion = posicion;
    }
}
```

Software usado

- JDK = 11
- Hibernate 6.0.0.Final
- MySQL connector 8.0.13
- javax.persistence-api 2.2

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias

Comment: falta que nos muestres tu archivo hibernate.cfg

Comment: @abrahamhs no, no hace falta pues no hay, la configuración esta en el main hecha en codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido solucionarlo, es problema de la version 6, con la version 5.6.9.Final funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Súper! Pudiste identificar por qué la versión 6 no funciona?

Comment: No, no tengo ni idea.

Comment: `6.0 moves from Java Persistence as defined by the Java EE specs to Jakarta Persistence as defined by the Jakarta EE spec. The most immediate impact of this change is that applications would need to be updated to use the Jakarata Persistence classes (jakarta.persistence.) instead of the Java Persistence ones (javax.persistence.).` en la [documentación](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html). Puede ser por ahí

Comment: Interesante. Me lo apunto y lo pruebo. Muchas gracias